# <f:image without width declaration creates a width-property in HTML that stays the same, even when the width of the original image changes

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I create an image-object with fuild widthout width-property:

```
<f:image src="EXT:my_template/Resources/Public/images/image.png" />
```

This create the HTML-Output:

```
<img src="typo3conf/ext/my_template/Resources/Public/images/image.png" width="526" height="725" alt="">
```

Now when I change the image.png with another width (for example width=200px) it still create the same HTML-Output and the image gets zoomed.

I flushed all caches in backend, deleted cache via install-tool and deleted the typo3temp folder. Still the HTML-Output adds the old width-property.

I have to put a width in the

What can I do? Where is this cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this "bug". The problem is, that TYPO3 caches the width/height properties in the sys_file_metadata database table and doesn't update the data at a change. You can change it manually but this is only a workaround.

Comment: Great info. One more thing, what if I delete a dataset in this table? or clean the hole table, will Typo3 rebuild it? Or would it cause chaos?

Comment: Good question. I didn't test it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug, it's usefull that TYPO3 save width and height of original picture for many differents uses...

The best solution I think is to let TYPO3 do that stuff...

So, you write your fluid code for img without width and height :

`<f:image src="EXT:my_template/Resources/Public/images/image.png" />`

and with css you add some properties for img tag :

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

So your image is responsive ;)

Or check the maxW and maxWInText values into "CONTENT" category constants.. maybe...

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean processed files in the install tool under "Clean up". Sometimes TYPO3 has problems to realize a file has changed when the filename stays the same.

Comment: I did this, the problem is, if you dont put any width-property to the f:image then it will not create a processed file anyway. It will take the original file in the HTML-Output. Like if I have a file 200x100 it will create a `<img src="typo3conf/ext/my_template/Resources/Public/images/image.png width="200" height="100">`. When I now change the file to 300x300 it still creates the same HTML-Output `<img src="typo3conf/ext/my_template/Resources/Public/images/image.png width="200" height="100">` (It's like it does not read the image anymore and keeps the old dimensions, no matter what)